# catkin_make_isolated does not create env.sh

Tags: ros, jenkins, catkin-make-isolated, third-party, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heyho,

I am trying to release a package containing a custom library for which we also use our custom build environment (which does add some convenient macros just as catkin would do). As it is all CMAKE I created a "wrapper" catkin package which will handle catkin dependencies and provide stuff like the package.xml (see https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/fzi_icl_core ).

This works really well as long as I use catkin_make to build my workspace. All sources get build and installed correctly and subsequent projects can list this as dependency and so on. When I tried to release it however jenkins failed during presumably trying to execute the code? Here is the output:

```
[ 82%] Built target test_icl_core_config
[ 83%] Built target test_icl_core_logging
[ 91%] Built target ts_icl_core
[ 93%] Built target ts_icl_core_config
[100%] Built target ts_icl_core_thread
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: /tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/share/tinyxml/tinyxml-config.cmake
-- Installing: /tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/lib/libtinyxml.so
< many many more lines of installing...>
-- Removed runtime path from "/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/bin/ts_icl_core"
-- Installing: /tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/bin/ts_icl_core_config
-- Removed runtime path from "/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/bin/ts_icl_core_config"
-- Installing: /tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/bin/ts_icl_core_thread
-- Removed runtime path from "/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/bin/ts_icl_core_thread"
Unhandled exception of type 'RuntimeError':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py", line 965, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py", line 670, in build_package
    "'\n  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is "
RuntimeError: No env.sh file generated at: '/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/env.sh'
  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.
  This can also occur when the cmake cache is stale, try --force-cmake.
<== Failed to process package 'fzi_icl_core': 
  No env.sh file generated at: '/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/env.sh'
  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.
  This can also occur when the cmake cache is stale, try --force-cmake.
Command failed, exiting.
# END SUBSECTION
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[WARNINGS]Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
```

Full output can be found here ( http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__fzi_icl_core__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/3/console ).
I get the same error when I build the package locally with the command

```
catkin_make_isolated
```

The suggested --force-cmake does not change anything in this regard.

So I see two solutions, both of which I have no idea how to implement:

1. Don't execute catkin_make_isolated (on the buildfarm)
2. Ensure that the env.sh file is correctly created

I guess that I have mixed something without declaring it correctly or something like that but I can not find specific documentation about this (other than the REP for catkin_make_isolated http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0134.html which does not seem to answer my problem) . Can somebody give me any pointers as to what I am missing?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231666/catkin_make_isolated-does-not-create-env.sh/) by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since your CMake code does not call `catkin_package()` anywhere it is not really a *catkin* package. Hence the message:

> This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.

You might want to read [REP 136](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0136.html). It might be sufficient if you declare the correct build type in your package manifest:

```
<export>
  <build_type>cmake</build_type>
</export>
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on 2016-04-11**:
The Problem with setting the build type to plain cmake I experienced was that I could not use it within a catkin workspace. I would always have to build it with the catkin_make_isolated command which I did not want. But when I use the build Type as you suggested the isolated build works. Thanks